# Using find_library() in cmake function

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

In my project I use function, which calles `find_library(...)`. Function is defined in `SomeScript.cmake`.
It works fine if called one time. But now I want to use it several time in my project. The problem is
that `find_library` caches the first result, and simply doesn`t run again.

So, the part I don't understand - function should provide it's own scope. But it looks like that there is,
only one "copy" of the function with all variables cached. Is it really so? And is there a correct way to use
`find_library(...)` inside a user function?

Comment: What do you expect? Cached are scans over your file system. A second rund should give the same result. Why do you hope to get different results the second time?

Comment: Well, honestly, for some reason, I expected that cmake function is more like a C++ (or any other language) function. I`m still confused about function scope. So there is no reasonable workaround here?

Comment: If every call to your function emits `find_library` with the **same parameters**, then caching is what do you need: no needs to actually search the same file under same directories the second time. If you use **different parameters** for `find_library` call, then use **different variables** for store results.

Comment: Well, thank you for the answer. The problem is - I tried to store result in internal function variable.

Comment: "I tried to store result in internal function variable" - The first parameter for `find_library` denotes the variable for store the result, and this variable is the CACHE'd one (that is, **global**). Well, you could use [unset(CACHE)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/unset.html) for destroy that variable (after you copy its content somewhere else). But generally one should avoid such things. Please, post **more detailed example** of your problem, including the code. So we would be able to provide more useful solutions.

Comment: Thank you! `unset(CACHE)` worked for me.

Comment: Glad to hear, but I think similar to Tsyvarev, that you make a conceptional mistake.